# Error al traer informacion de la BD en laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo una tabla student con la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y una tabla TestAuth con esta estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver ambas están relacionadas con la tabla Group, estoy intentando consultar a los estudiantes que pertenecen al mismo grupo con el que esta asociado testAuth a traves de esta consulta:

```
    $students = Student::where('group_id', Auth::user()->group_id)->get();return view('testauth/start', compact('students'));
```

Pero obtengo este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué hay en la linea 18 de testAuthController.php?

Comment: `$students = Student::where('group_id', Auth::user()->group_id)->get();`

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos un dd() de `Auth::user()`?

Comment: Retorna null siendo que ya estoy logueado.

Comment: Creo saber donde esta el error, este modelo para autenticarse utiliza un guard distinto al del User,  `'guards' => [
        'testauth' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'testauths',
        ],` Entonces No seria Auth::user()?.

Comment: Ya encontré el problema, aunque no la solución, el problema es que la ruta /testauth/start no se encuentra protegida por la autentificacion, por ende no retorna ningun usuario logueado.

Answer (score 0):

Problema solucionado, había que añadir los middleware a las rutas donde se estaba trabajando, en especial el web y el del nuevo guard que autenticaba al usuario testauth.